# SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error) nested select order by

Tags: sql, sqlite, jdbc

I have this query that I execute using JDBC:

```
String query = "(SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY age;";
```

I get the

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)
```

error.

Does sqlite not allow brackets? How should I change it to get 10 last people inserted, sorted by age?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.* FROM people p ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) p
ORDER BY age
```